# What does the star (*) in instance documentation mean?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, haddock

In the [MonadState doc page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Class.html#t:MonadState), there's a star (*) inside the `ReaderT` type of the `MonadState` instance:

```
MonadState s m => MonadState s (ReaderT * r m)
```

But actually in the source, there's no star:

```
instance MonadState s m => MonadState s (ReaderT r m) where
```

So what does the star mean in the doc?